# github ssh public key not found with node.js child_process.spawn() on windows, but visible on child_process.exec()

Tags: git, node.js, github, ssh

This code works on Windows and on Mac OS X:

```
var exec = require( 'child_process' ).exec
exec( 'git clone git@github.com:user/myrepo.git' )
```

But this code returns an "Access denied(publickey)" error from git when running on Windows, but not on Mac OS X:

```
var spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawn
 ,  child = spawn( 'git', [ 'clone', 'git@github.com:user/myrepo.git' ], { env: process.env } )

child.on.stderr( 'data', function( data ) { 
  console.log( data.toString() )
})
```

I assume in `spawn` i'm losing my connection to `~/.ssh`... but I thought sending in `process.env` would work.  By the way, the `git clone` commands work fine on Windows when typed into the command prompt directly.

Anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not a Node problem, but a `git` problem.  Upgraded git on Windows from 1.7.11 to 1.8.3 and the spawn worked.

Comment: Good to know. The bash packaged within msysgit must have changed. +1

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the environment variables are lost in a classic node.js `spaw()` function, especially `HOME` (which isn't defined by default in windows, and is necessary for ssh to find its keys)

Maybe a spawn like [win-spawn](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/win-spawn) would work better:

> Spawn for `node.js` but in a way that works regardless of which OS you're using. Use this if you want to use spawn with a JavaScript file.
>
> It works by explicitly invoking node on windows.
> **It also shims support for environment variable setting by [attempting to parse the command with a regex](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/win-spawn/blob/master/index.js#L35-L47)**.
> Since all modification is wrapped in `if (os === 'Windows_NT')`, it can be safely used on non-windows systems and will not break anything.

Comment: win-spawn seems like an odd hack considering windows is a supported target for node -- spawn() should work.  doing more research.